# Construir base de dados

Tags: sql, r

Preciso construir uma base de dados com 200 linhas e 4 colunas (com as 4 variáveis que idealizei). Idealizei um estudo para estimar a presença de cobras em uma determinada cidade, não tenho dados. Pensei que a presença das cobras deve-se a estas 4 variáveis: Precipitação, temperatura, Presença da cobra (1-sim; 0-não), Estações do ano (1-Primavera, 2-Verão, 3-Outono, 4-Inverno). Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Ta, mas em que você precisa ajuda ?... Quer saber quual o banco de dados mais viavel ? Como fazer ? O que vai precisar ? Sua pergunta está meio vaga...

Comment: quero saber como faço o script para construir os dados, quando não tenho dados :|

Answer (score 4):

Em **PostgreSQL** pode-se usar a função `random()` para simular tais dados sem necessidade de uma linguagem externa, somente com SQL. Imagino que seja algo facilmente transportável a outros sistemas de bancos de dados.

Primeiramente, criei uma tabela com as especificações dadas na pergunta:

```sql
create table presenca_de_cobras (
  precipitacao numeric(4,1) not null,
  temperatura int not null,
  presenca boolean not null,
  estacao int not null,
  constraint estacoes check (estacao in (1,2,3,4))
);
```

Cada campo deve possuir uma amplitude de dados diferente, como precipitação em centenas de milímetros, imagino, e a presença de serpentes em booleano "true" ou "false".

A função `random()` retorna um valor aleatório de 0 a 1, portanto multiplique pelo limite máximo do valor em questão. Além de `random()`, utilizei a função `floor()` para arredondar para baixo o valor aleatório de estação e a `generate_series()` para construir uma tabela de cem registros, mas não preciso dos dados que ela retorna. Tudo isso é passado ao `INSERT` que populará a tabela:

```sql
-- insere os dados
insert into presenca_de_cobras 
select 
  (random()*200)::numeric(4,1) precipitacao,  -- precipitacao de 0-200 milimetros
  (random()*40)::int temperatura,             -- temperatura de 0-40 graus
  (random() > 0.5) presenca,                  -- presenca TRUE ou FALSE
  floor(random()*4+1)::int estacao            -- estação de 1-4
from generate_series(1,100) as s;
```

Por fim, é só consultar a tabela em si:

```sql
select * from presenca_de_cobras limit 10;
```

```
| precipitacao | temperatura | presenca | estacao |
|--------------|-------------|----------|---------|
|        137.2 |          16 |    false |       4 |
|        164.5 |          38 |    false |       3 |
|          4.3 |          14 |     true |       3 |
|        134.9 |          38 |    false |       2 |
|          3.9 |          18 |    false |       3 |
|         67.3 |          37 |    false |       1 |
|        140.3 |          34 |     true |       3 |
|         34.2 |          35 |     true |       4 |
|         56.3 |          37 |     true |       1 |
|        171.5 |           5 |     true |       4 |
```

---

Segue SQL Fiddle com todos os passos: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/693a3/31/0

Comment: Não retornou nenhuma estação 1, será que o aleatório só está pegando do 2 ao 4?

Comment: @FilipeRicardo obrigado por apontar o erro! Realmente, defini um "range" errado na hora de multiplicar o `random()`

Answer (score 4):

Eu resolveria este problema da seguinte maneira utilizando o `R`. Vou definir o número de linhas do meu banco de dados:

```
n <- 200
```

Vou criar `n` valores aleatórios para a precipitação, temperatura e presença de cobras com as distribuições exponencial, normal e binomial, respectivamente:

```
set.seed(1234) # para que os resultados sejam reproduziveis
precipitacao <- round(rexp(n, rate=2), digits=1)
temperatura  <- round(rnorm(n, mean=25), digits=0)
presenca     <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob=0.2)
```

Em seguida, vou criar um vetor chamado `estacao`, com as estações do ano definidas:

```
estacao <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each=n/4)
```

Por fim, junto tudo em um objeto só, chamado dados:

```
dados <- data.frame(precipitacao, temperatura, presenca, estacao)
head(dados)
##    precipitacao temperatura presenca estacao
## 1           1.3          25        0       1
## 2           0.1          23        0       1
## 3           0.0          26        0       1
## 4           0.9          26        0       1
## 5           0.2          27        0       1
## 6           0.0          26        0       1
## 7           0.4          26        1       1
## 8           0.1          25        0       1
## 9           0.4          25        1       1
## 10          0.4          27        0       1
```

Note que não assumi nenhum tipo de dependência entre as variáveis. Por exemplo, a geração dos números que indicam a presença ou não de cobras não vai ter, neste exemplo, relação com a precipitação ou com a temperatura registrados. Tudo aqui foi gerado de maneira aleatória e independente. Talvez os dados coletados futuramente não exibam este comportamento.

Comment: Marcus Nunes porque você colocou set.seed (1234) ? Porquê esse numero?

Comment: Para que os resultados sejam reprodutíveis. `set.seed` determina qual semente utilizar para gerar os números. Escolhi 1234 porque gosto deste valor.

Comment: Como faço para adicionar 4 linhas à base de dados em que, de modo alternado, cada uma das 4 variáveis possui um missing (NA)?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o banco pode ser criado com os seguintes comandos:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Estudo;
CREATE TABLE Persons (
id int,
precipitacao varchar(255),
temperatura varchar(255),
estacao varchar(255),
presenca Serpente boolean 
);
```

Daí basta popular a tabela como quiser, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -2):

pode começar com a função

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
);
```